# How to display something from array with another name in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array that returns one element $name, and I want to display it with another name.

For example:

`$name = 'PC'` and I want to display it as 'PC COMPUTER', first array displays element which is true, how to compare this elements with another array to display it with that other names?

Comment: Sorry, could you describe that a bit better? Could you show your actual code?

Comment: People can't guess exactly what you want post the both array content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just make a second array and load it up with more descriptive names, then use the first as a key?

```
$name = 'PC';
$description =  array('PC' => 'PC COMPUTER');
echo $descriptions[$name];
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, it was so easy :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$array[$name] = 'PC COMPUTER'
& Post ur array .give a eg: